# Could not find driver (PDO exception with Laravel)

Tags: postgresql, laravel-5, pdo

I have researched this problem extensively and I have tried everything that has been suggested, but I think I may have missed something. I have a laravel project with the following configuration for .env:

```
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=oamileage
DB_USERNAME=postgres
DB_PASSWORD=********
```

I have also uncommented the following line in php.ini:

```
;extension=pdo_pgsql -> extension=pdo_pgsql
```

I get the following error when I try to use php artisan migrate:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = public and table_name = migrations)
```

A side note: I already have pgsql up and running for another project of mine (which is unrelated to laravel) and it's working without a problem. I am on windows.

I have my PDO drivers installed, as seen here: [image]

Comment: Just because you uncommented something somewhere doesn't mean you did it right (in right location). What does `phpinfo()` say? Is the `PDO Postgresql` module loaded? If not, on the top of the page, you will find the right location of the `php.ini` used.

Comment: Yes, the PDO Postgresql is loaded as per phpinfo() output. I followed the phpinfo() for the php.ini address and I'm certain I did it right. I already have postgresql up and running for another project that is unrelated to laravel, it's just that it's not working on laravel.

Comment: PHP cli and Apache use different config files. Check if this is also enabled in the cli version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the php cli has another config file installed elsewhere (the path can be found in phpinfo()). I uncommented the following line, according to madflow and it worked:

```
;extension=pdo_pgsql -> extension=pdo_pgsql
```

Answer (score 3):

You just need to install:

> sudo apt-get install php7.2-pgsql

After the previous command you can migrate your models to database:

> php artisan migrate

Comment: I did sudo apt-get install php-pgsql